# Payment Shopping cart - Laravel different Objects

Tags: laravel

I try to add different objets to my shopping Cart view in laravel, but I get an exception when I try to add different objects to the view. I would like to know if someone knows a good practice to achieve this.

Here my Class to get item type number 1:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class CartCotisationStructure
{
    public $items = null ;
    public $totalQty = 0 ;
    public $totalPrice = 0 ;



    public function __construct($oldCart)

    {
        if ($oldCart){

            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;

        }
    }

    public function  add($item , $id){
        $storedItem = ['qty' => 0 , 'montant' => $item->montant , 'item' => $item];

        if($this->items){
            if(array_key_exists($id , $this->items)){
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->montant * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->montant;

    }

}
```

here my item type number two :

```
<?php

namespace App;


class CartLicenceStructure
{
    public $items = null ;
    public $totalQty = 0 ;
    public $totalPrice = 0 ;



    public function __construct($oldCart)

    {
        if ($oldCart){

            $this->items = $oldCart->items;
            $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
            $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;

        }
    }

    public function  add($item , $id){
        $storedItem = ['qty' => 0 , 'mt_cotisation' => $item->activite_licencie->mt_cotisation , 'item' => $item];

        if($this->items){
            if(array_key_exists($id , $this->items)){
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty']++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->activite_licencie->mt_cotisation * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->activite_licencie->mt_cotisation;

    }


}
```

here my controller for LicenceStructure :

```
 public function getAddToCart(Request $request , $id){


        $licencie = LicencieStructure::find($id);

        $oldCart = Session::has('CartLicenceStructure') ? Session::get('CartLicenceStructure') : null ;
        $cart = new CartLicenceStructure($oldCart);

        $cart->add($licencie , $licencie->id);

        $request->session()->put('CartLicenceStructure' , $cart);

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('status', 'Le licencié à bien été ajouté au panier');;
    }


    public function getCart()
    {
        if(!Session::has('CartLicenceStructure')){

            return view('shop.panier');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('CartLicenceStructure');
        $cart = new CartLicenceStructure($oldCart);
        return view('shop.panier' , ['licencies' => $cart->items , 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);

    }
```

here my controller for Cotisations

```
    public function getAddToCartCotisation(Request $request , $id){


        $cotisation = CotisationStructure::find($id);

        $oldCart = Session::has('CartLicenceStructure') ? Session::get('CartCotisationStructure') : null ;
        $cart = new CartCotisationStructure($oldCart);

        $cart->add($cotisation , $cotisation->id);

        $request->session()->put('CartCotisationStructure' , $cart);

        return redirect()->route('home')->with('status', 'La cotisation à bien été ajouté au panier');;
    }


    public function getCartCotisation()
    {
        if(!Session::has('CartCotisationStructure')){

            return view('shop.panier');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('CartCotisationStructure');
        $cart = new CartCotisationStructure($oldCart);

        return view('shop.panier' , ['cotisations' => $cart->items , 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice]);

    }
```

And here my view ( who make an exception when i want to add two different items , "undefined variable "licences" )

```
 @if(Session::has('CartLicenceStructure'))

                        @foreach($licencies as $licencie)
// display the items 
                        @endforeach

@elseif(Session::has('CartCotisationStructure')

 @foreach($cotisations as $cotisation)

// display the items 
                        @endforeach
```

Comment: Please take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) page about how to write a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example (take a good look at the Minimal part ;) )

Comment: examples should be in English, not in French